# URL Rewriting contra Making Folders with index files

Tags: url-rewriting

I hope this is not the wrong place to ask this, but this is driving me crazy. I'm making a website with a friend.

He've structered everything. I took a look and the site and it said

`http://site.com/account/`

I thought to myself, good, he is using url rewriting.

So today I found out that there were no url rewriting, he had crated folders with index files. So the example above would work like this:

Our public_html would have like twelve folders, each containing an index file. When I saw this, I told him I found it very unprofessional and asked him to change it. He's telling me that it doesn't make a difference since the outcome is the same, visitor wise.

What disadvantages are the from using his method contra url rewriting?

One thing that comes to my mind is that i have to change the source of every css file, scripts etc. whenever I enter a folder.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about unprofessional part but this approach is definitely a maintenance nightmare. Today he has created 12 folders with their `index.html`, css, js files etc. Tomorrow your website may expand (who doesn't want to expand) and you will need more folders. You may need sub-sub URLs like:

```
http://site.com/category/books
http://site.com/category/books/fiction
http://site.com/category/electronics
http://site.com/category/food/organic
```

etc etc. How long he can keep creating folder and sub folders like this.

Let's say he's doesn't mind and is ready to do it hard way. But what are you guys going to do if some day you want to change look & feel of your website. How many `index.html`, css, js file are you going to change?

My 2 cents: Use some CMS.

Comment: THank you for you answer :) We're creating a custom CMS :)